# Ubuntu 18.04: Failed to find module 'mesa' when loading kernel modules

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, intel-graphics, mesa

I recently turned on my laptop upon returning home and found that it would not start DE properly, exhibiting 'Load Kernel Modules' errors and forcing me to use tty2 through 6 to achieve anything. Upon running `sudo ./systemd-modules-load` from `/lib/systemd/`, the following message is displayed:

```
Failed to find module 'mesa'
```

Additional notes:

I am running an Intel HD Graphics 4000 graphics chipset and was able to boot perfectly fine less than 2 hours earlier without making any updates.

EDIT - Found the issue: a graphics library was missing.

Comment: Always post `uname` of your system. If you `/sbin/modprobe mesa` what is the output? Do you see `mesa.ko.xz` under `/lib/modules` for your kernel? How old is the laptop? Does it have a HDD or SSD storage?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions ajeh, but I found the issue. For some reason libwayland-egl1 was missing and was causing countless errors upon booting. I managed to enter tty2, connect to the internet, download the package and reboot. This fixed everything.